# Font-awesome icons are not vertically centered

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using the latest font-awesome library (4.4) and it seems some icons are not vertically centered or they have different sizes.

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/6or8h5z0/)

I made a zoom over a `font-size: 14px;` list here:

[image]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Set line-height for the font.

Comment: No, they wouldn't be...that's the way the glyphs are drawn. some have descnders like lower case q for instance - http://jsfiddle.net/6or8h5z0/1/

Comment: I've met the same problem. The glyph containers are squared and the height depends of the width of the icon (also like @Paulie_D said there are some descenders). The only way I found is to set each position manually.

Comment: @Paulie_D It seems you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.quick-actions i {
    font-size: 54px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.fa:before {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.quick-actions{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This seems to work...
http://jsfiddle.net/nh1sgw1a/

Edit (I see it really is a problem with fa-commenting-o):

```
.quick-actions i.fa-commenting-o:before{
    font-size:50px;
    /*margin-top:-5px;*/
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nh1sgw1a/2/

Comment: It improves it a bit, but still not being perfect. The "comments" icon seem not to fit properly. [Quite obvious with small icons](http://jsfiddle.net/nh1sgw1a/1/).

Comment: I know, but for that class add other proprieties... http://jsfiddle.net/nh1sgw1a/2/ .quick-actions i.fa-commenting-o:before{
    font-size:50px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    float:left;
}

Comment: Right I see. Btw, the `line-height:50px;` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Like said in the comments, they aren't drawn centered in the middle of the horizontal axis *of its shape*, and that's why they look like being in different heights. 
That said, I found this CSS rule useful to place them closer to the middle edge of my buttons/bars (more vertically centered, although not perfect):

```
i.fa {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```